# Fixing - "Cannot assign to non-mutable" compilation error

Tags: android, clojure

I applied the patch [clj-1472-2](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/secure/attachment/15351/clj-1472-2.patch) described [here](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1472) to clojure 1.8, but when I used this patched version of clojure to build a library that depends on core.async, the compilation fails:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot assign to non-mutable: value, compiling:(clojure/core/memoize.clj:58:7)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot assign to non-mutable: value, compiling:(clojure/core/memoize.clj:58:7)
```

This occurs in RetryingDelay ([memoize.clj](https://github.com/clojure/core.memoize/blob/core.memoize-0.5.9/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/memoize.clj)) due to the patched change to the locking macro:

```
(deftype RetryingDelay [fun ^:volatile-mutable available? ^:volatile-mutable value]
  clojure.lang.IDeref
  (deref [this]
    ;; first check (safe with volatile flag)
    (if available?
      value
      (locking fun
        ;; second check (race condition with locking)
        (if available?
          value
          (do
            ;; fun may throw - will retry on next deref
            (let [v (fun)]
              ;; this ordering is important - MUST set value before setting available?
              ;; or you have a race with the first check above
              (set! value v)
              (set! available? true)
              v)))))))
```

locking macro after the patch:

```
(defmacro locking
  "Executes exprs in an implicit do, while holding the monitor of x.
  Will release the monitor of x in all circumstances."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [x & body]
  `(let [lockee# ~x]
     (clojure.lang.Util/lock lockee# (^{:once true} fn* [] ~@body))))
```

Where Util/lock is:

```
static public Object lock(final Object lockee, final IFn f) {
    synchronized(lockee) {
        return f.invoke();
    }
}
```

Why does this error occur?

What would be an appropriate change to resolve it?

**Update**

I should have probably mentioned that the reason for attempting to build a patched version of clojure is to be able to run jars written in clojure on Android (Lollipop and later) as part of a java app (not a complete app in clojure), this [CLJ-1472](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1472) provides more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this occurs because the `locking` macro puts the body of `locking` into a `fn` and inside that `fn` you do not have access to the mutable fields of the outer deftype scope.

The simplest way to implement low-level stuff like this is to just do it in Java, not in Clojure (that way you also don't need to depend on a non-applied patch).

Something like this (I have not tried to compile this, so this may have minor errors):

```
public class RetryingDelay implements clojure.lang.IDeref {
  private final IFn fun;
  private volatile boolean available;
  private volatile Object value;

  public RetryingDelay(IFn fun) {
    this.fun = fun;
  }

  public Object deref() {
    if(available) {
      return value;
    } else {
      synchronized(fun) {
        if(available) {
          return value;
        } else {
          Object v = fun.invoke();
          value = v;
          available = true;
          return v;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for your response. OK, I think I understand what you are saying as to why this is happening (I'm not a macro expert), but your suggestion of just doing it in java needs more explanation, for me at least! I added an update to my question to give it more context, as I'm not clear what would be implemented in Java and how I could avoid doing a patch (if that's what you meant). Thanks

Comment: Added rough Java translation.

Comment: With this Java impl, you no longer depend on the fix for CLJ-1472 being applied.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will give that a go. Excuse my ignorance, but is there a way I can get memoize to utilise this implementation rather than the deftype it defines? Additionally whilst this would hopefully fix things for memoize, other libraries could be using the locking macro so would fall foul of the original issue.

Comment: Re this change - would need to be patched in core.memoize to take effect. You could do so by forking the project.

Re the original patch, this is good feedback on why this patch would not address the issue.

Comment: This worked, which is great. I patched core.memoize and implemented your suggested RetryingDelay, my only change was to also include "available" and "value" in the constructor. This does mean I can now make some progress, although personally I would prefer a better solution to the problem identified in CLJ-1472